# How to run docker for desktop without starting containers

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

Sometimes I want to run docker for desktop without starting the containers automatically upon startup and to choose which one I want to load manually to resolve some problems (Sometimes docker doesn't have memory to load all of them and sometimes it crashes so i want to do it selectively).

Is there a CLI parameter or configuration file change to achieve that?

Docker for desktop for windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

To update all of your containers, to not start,

`docker update --restart=no $(docker ps -a -q)`

If you need to access the docker root directory, where the images and containers are stored for example, they are at `c:\ProgramData\Docker`and you need to know the container ID and then access the config file for you to change the restart policy before Docker starts.

Comment: But how can i run docker command when docker  for desktop is not started? if i start docker it will automatically run the containers...  i want to change the settings *before* running the container because docker crash because of the container.

Comment: You have to change the settings before stopping docker.